# Android studio app does not want compile when I add libs

Tags: java, android

I made an app with rewarded video from appodeal. Everything was ok but something happened and the app stopped compiling with libs from appodeal, with error: Dex merge error. What is going wrong?

logs :

> Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use
>   'implementation' instead. :app:buildInfoDebugLoader :app:preBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugAidl
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResValues
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE :app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugSources :app:javaPreCompileDebug
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:packageInstantRunResourcesDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkManifestChangesDebug
>   :app:transformClassesWithExtractJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithDependencyCheckerForDebug
>   :app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
>   :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
>   :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug
>   :app:transformNativeLibsAndResourcesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug
>   :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug
>   :app:transformClassesEnhancedWithInstantReloadDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:incrementalDebugTasks :app:preColdswapDebug
>   :app:fastDeployDebugExtractor UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugInstantRunAppInfo UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
>   :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
>   :app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
>   dex

Comment: can you please post the `Logcat` Error

Comment: Here it is: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: You can use search first the error here. 

this links [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46591042/5343866) might helps you

Comment: show full error. It usually contains details about what exactly is wrong.

Comment: I cant paste it to the comment, so it will be in the answers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I updated my google play services.

Here is what solved the problem for me :

- Clean
- Rebuild

If that doesn't work try :

- File -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

If this didn't work :
- Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48494163/unable-to-merge-dex-error-in-android-studio-when-adding-a-specific-compile-in) it would surely help !!

Comment: No, it didnt help me, any other suggestions how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Adding this fixed it

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
                  }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your gradle file? and tell me which version of Android Studio are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the easiest way for me was just create new project and import everything from project with error and everything become work without any: multiDexEnabled or project clean.

Answer (score 0):

Highly likely you have duplicate libs/classes in the project. I suggest you check dependencies in build.gradle, check /libs folder.

[Check this out. It also might help you to identify the problem you have.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267621/unable-to-merge-dex)